# writing to csv, only the last line ends up in the file python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, csv

When writing to a csv file, only the last row is written.

Here's the code

```
   item_keys = []
   item_values = []
   item_values2 = []#to build the list of lists
    # added newline='' because in Python3 this is required to keep an extra row being added
    with open(filename+'.csv','w',newline='') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for key, value in jcr_rows.items():
            if write_header:
            item_keys.append(key)
            item_values.append(value)
        if write_header:
            writer.writerow(item_keys)
            write_header = False
        print(item_values)
        writer.writerow(item_values)
```

The "print(item_values)" shows two lists:

```
['', '1.92469', '3.394', '8.1', '98.24', '220.54971', '1.053',
'1932-6203', '3.7', '22,077', '2611', '2.806', 'PLoS One', '2.615',
'77.344', '0.429', 'PLOS ONE', '508,248']
['', '0.00155', 'Not Available', '8.4', '83.54', '0.17802', 
'Not Available', '1024-2708','7.5', '79', '7567', '1.111', 'HONG KONG 
MEDICAL JOURNAL', '1.062','40.584', '0.405', 'HONG KONG MED J', '1,228']
```

But only the second one gets written. If I change the write mode to "a", the headers are duplicated for each row.

I have tried using writerows instead of writerow, but that splits the content up by at the character, and still only for one row.

I have tried adding

```
for x in item_values:
    writer.writerow(x)
```

this separated the characters for one row, also.

I have tried building the lists into a list of lists to use with writerows but that hasn't gone well either.

I have been round and round with this, and now I am spinning my wheels.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: 
The expected output is a row of headers, which are printed with rows of related data underneath

```
JCR Abbreviated Title   Citable Items   ISSN       etc 
PLOS ONE                22,077          1932-6203 
HONG KONG MED J         79              1024-2708
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output you want to have please ? like that we can understand better your problem

Comment: I have updated the post with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I sorted it out. I built a list of lists `item_values2.append(item_values)` but had my statement where I declared the `item_value` variable in the wrong place in the loop.

Then, I was able to use writerows to get the desired output.